# Messenger requires secure callback url

Tags: callback, facebook-messenger, callbackurl

When creating a Messenger chat bot you must force people to subscribe to your page before they can use it.
To do this you need a Secure Callback URL, a standard http:// address won't do, it must be https://

I don't have a Secure Callback URL to my disposal. Can anyone recommend a site/way for me to get one?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your domain name with cloudflare to use it as a proxy between the user & your webserver.

You can enable their flexible SSL which is free of charge and very easy to configure. You can find more details [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170516-How-do-I-add-SSL-to-my-site) and [here](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-universal-ssl/). I've recently configured my FB Chatbot webhook with cloudflare free SSL and it works pretty well.